# Invalid pattern in vectorizer standardization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-preprocessing

I am trying to separate unique characters from words so I can threat them as separate tokens.

This is my vectorizer:

```py
vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
                standardize=code_standaridization,
                split="whitespace",
                output_mode="int",
                output_sequence_length=params["input_dim"],
            )
```

And this is my function:

```
def code_standaridization(input_data):
    """
    Helps with finding correct embedding.
    """
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "-", " - ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "_", " _ ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "(", " ( ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, ")", " ) ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "{", " { ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "}", " } ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "[", " [ ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "]", " ] ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, '"', ' " ')
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "'", " ' ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, ".", " . ")
    input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, ",", " , ")

    return input_data
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Node: 'StaticRegexReplace_2'
Invalid pattern: (, error: missing ): (
     [[{{node StaticRegexReplace_2}}]] [Op:__inference_adapt_step_133]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`regex_replace()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/regex_replace) uses the RE2 syntax defined [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), which notes:

> The simplest regular expression is a single literal character. Except for the metacharacters like `*+?()|`, characters match themselves. To match a metacharacter, escape it with a backslash: `\+` matches a literal plus character.

So, you should add backslashes for replacing parentheses:

```py
input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "\(", " \( ")
input_data = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, "\)", " \) ")
```